# Cassandra: insert value and update average/min/max

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am thinking of using Cassandra for time series data in a Java application. I also need the average (and min/max) for the last *n* minutes.

The simple approach is to make three calls from the client:

1. insert the new value
2. select the average, min and max over the recent *n* minutes
3. update the average

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

The first and second step use the same partition, and thus will run on the same node. Thus a round-trip could be saved if both statement could be executed in the same request. But BATCH does not support select (as far as I understand).

The third request involves a different partition (and thus likely a different node). The benefit of using BATCH would be that both tables remain in sync. And I think it would also save a client -> coordinator round trip. But BATCH does not support passing the results from a select to an update (as far as I know).

```
create table metrics (
  resource_name text,
  metric_name text,
  recorded_at timestamp,
  value double,
  primary key ((resource_name, metric_name), recorded_at)
) with clustering order by (recorded_at desc);

create table last_30m (
  metric_name text,
  resource_name text,
  avg_value double,
  min_value double,
  max_value double,
  primary key (metric_name, resource_name)
) with clustering order by (resource_name asc);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `avg`, `min`, and `max` aggregate functions (as of 2.2). So you dont really need a table for this, you can just query for it. The data will all be sequential on disk or in memtables since sorted by `recorded_at`

`SELECT avg(value), min(value), max(value) FROM metrics WHERE resource_name = 'blarg' AND metric_name = 'cpu' AND recorded_at > {half hour ago}`

In the future there will be a `now()-30m` (CASSANDRA-11936) but for now you have to manually compute and put the "half hour ago" value in.

I would strongly recommend avoiding BATCH and updating a 2nd table for this and just make the query to read the value when you need it. If you are concerned about the performance of the above query, test it before making an optimization that will in all likelihood be more expensive. If you need things like "average for past day" it may be worth it, but I would not do it as part of your updates but more of a "every minute update" kinda thing (also consider spark streaming)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will test it first to assess performance.